# Limiting Access to Certain User Profiles

Tags: security, drupal, drupal-7

How can I limit access to user profiles so that only users with a specific role can be viewed globally.

What I'm trying to do is make accessing users with "writer" role possible for all users, but leave normal members inaccessible to all but admin.

Comment: You might want to see whether the [Profile 2 module](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) might be able to help you. The writer role would then have permission to create a profile for all to see while others do not. Also, you could modify the way users list other users' profiles. You could use the Views module use a filter so that it only shows users of a certain role.

Comment: Should have put that in as a comment, I'd have voted you up.

Answer (score 0):

(Originally posted this as a comment but I guessed it helped so I'm posting it as an answer.)

You might want to see whether the [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module might be able to help you. The writer role would then have permission to create a profile for all to see while others do not. Also, you could modify the way users list other users' profiles. You could use the Views module use a filter so that it only shows users of a certain role